# Recreate Matomo transitions in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Matomo has a very usefull dialog called transitions.
[image]

Is it possible to recreate something like this in Google Analytics?

Comment: You cant in google analytics, however, you can create something similar using google charts.  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey or could also possibly be done with D3.js https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/013054e8d7807dff76247b81b0e29030